# How to have two overlapping elements within a responsive div without causing issues with absolute?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to create a site where there are overlapping elements contained with a responsive div.

```
<div>
<div class="row" style="position:relative">
  <img src=... style="position:absolute">
  <button style = "position:absolute">
</div>
<div class="row"></div>
  ...
<div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Desired]

The code works well and is responsive with bootstrap originally, but once I added the absolute, the image inside the 2nd row (Img 2) moves up to overlap the first row and seem to be no longer affected by the outside div. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have position: relative added to your parent containers style, ***Div 1*** I see a reference to row, is that the first DIV you are referencing in your photo? Please add your relative code as a snippit or in code formatting tildes ` ` `

Comment: There are built in classes for positioning in bootstrap have you tried them?

Comment: The div containing the absolute elements is relative, but not the biggest div that contains it. The divs also have bootstrap classes responsible for positioning, which I did not include for simplicity (col + offsets)